# Basic Python Vigenere Cypher

Tags: python-3.x, vigenere

I have the Basic of the code laid out the problem is I do not know how to use the length of the keyword correctly.

When I run the problem I just get a bunch of S's as my output cause the code is not going to the next letter of the keyword.

I need help in the Def Encrypt part (the second def)

Keyword is SECRET // This is input

```
def encrypt_letter(text_letter , code_letter):
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
index = alphabet.find(code_letter)
cypher = alphabet[index:]+alphabet[:index]
index2 = alphabet.find(text_letter.upper())
result = cypher[index2]
if text_letter.islower():
    result = result.lower()
return result

def encrypt(text, code):  
  cypher_text = ''
  for letter in text:
    if letter.isalpha():
        cypher_text += code_word[0:1:6] 
       # code_letter = ?
       # encrypt_letter(letter, )
    else:
        cypher_text += letter
  return cypher_text

code_word = input('Please enter the code word: ')
code_word = code_word.upper()

cypher_text = encrypt(plain_text, code_word)

print(cypher_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is clearly a student problem set, work on it a little longer and come back to ask a specific question, but a few hints:

1. Initialize a counter to count how many letters `.isalpha()` you've encountered
2. Use `counter % len(secret_code)` to keep track of your current position in the secret code
3. Use ASCII integer arithmetic and some `if/else` logic to modify characters in the `cypher_text` by `counter % len(secret_code)`
4. `ord()` and `chr()` will help you

If you're really stuck and need to peek at a solution, mine's here: https://github.com/bennett39/learning-exercises/blob/master/cs50/pset6/vigenere/vigenere.py

Spend a little more time on your solution before clicking that link, though.